# word 2013 : using macro to update indexes

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a **word document with several different indexes - and I am looking to automate the update of the index via a macro**.

But I fail to find the vba statement to do so ; using the macro recorder, I cannot update anymore the index and then, the recorder cannot record this command.

Comment: looks like already solved : http://superuser.com/questions/196703/how-do-i-update-all-fields-in-a-word-document

Comment: Hi Joe
If you need to work with fields in the future, when recording a macro, you can use keyboard commands: Alt + F9 toggles field code display on/off for the entire document; Shfit+F9 toggles the currently selected field's display; Ctrl+F9 inserts field code brackets; F9 updates a field; Ctrl+A, F9 will update all fields in the current story; Ctrl+Shift+F9 will change a field to plain text.